# Get facebook user ID instead app scoped ID using Graph API Explorer

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, search, userid

Facebook Graph API Explorer 1.0 displays user ID instead app scoped ID when viewing group members, but now V1.0 seems obsolete and i only able to use Graph API Explorer v2.0 and above!
Is there away to display Facebook user ID instead app scoped ID in V2.0?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to get the "real" ID of a user anymore in Apps created after April 2014 (v2.x+). Else the whole concept with the App Scoped ID would be senseless. More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: But how can i use V1.0?
I'm only able to use V2.0 and above in Graph API Explorer!

Comment: you can´t use v1.0 in a newer app, you can only use it with an app created before april 2014 (before v2.0 was introduced). and it would be pointless, because you don´t need the real id and it will stop working after april 2015 - which is pretty soon.